# locator service to use with ArcGIS Javascript API v2.1

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding

I am hoping to find a locator service that will locate by address or intersection, and that will work with version 2.1 of the ArcGIS Javascript API.

I tried this locator given in the examples, which works well with 3.1, but it doesn't seem to work with 2.1 :

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/jav...r_address.html

Unfortunately I think I need to stick with v2.1.  SO far I haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance, Jason

Comment: this was answered by kelly Hutchins on ESRI forums: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/64790-addresss-intersection-locator-service-for-v2.1?highlight=locator+service+ArcGIS+Javascript+API+v2.1